# Перенос сайта с Windows на Debian. Node js

Tags: linux, windows, node.js

Можно ли перенести сайт с Windows на Debian, который сделан на node js. Ну и степень сложности такого переноса, для оценки необходимости

Comment: зависит от того. что использует. если только SPA, то сбилдил, натравил nginx и все

Comment: Не SPA, там полноценный сайт с бд.

Comment: 1) Можно. 2) Степень сложности зависит от функциональности. Поскольку вы не привели её -- то оценивать нечего.